# parsing complex api json data recursively using python

Tags: python, json, rest, recursion

method which takes key as input and search for that key in whole json data and return list of key value pair of that key

this method working fine for normal key value pair `{'key':'some value'}` but if the value for key is list or dictionary `{'keya':[1,2,3]}` it returning empty list

```
filedata=open('testdata.json','r')
filedata=json.loads(filedata)
def extract_values(obj, key):
"""Pull all values of specified key from nested JSON."""
arr = []

def extract(obj, arr, key):
    """Recursively search for values of key in JSON tree."""
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                extract(v, arr, key)
            elif k == key:
                arr.append(v)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            extract(item, arr, key)
    return arr

results = extract(obj, arr, key)
return results
z=extract_values(filedata,'text')
print(z)
```

Comment: Here, a reproducible example of the JSON may help to find why the list is blank.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should always include a minimal example of the data so that the problem/deficiency can be reproduced and solutions can be tested - the easier you  make it for potential *answerers* the more solutions you might get..  Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function that, if the given object is a dict, yields the value if the given key exists in the dict and then recursively yields from the dict values, or yields from list items if the object is a list:

```
def extract(obj, key):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if key in obj:
            yield obj[key]
        for k, v in obj.items():
            yield from extract(v, key)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in obj:
            yield from extract(i, key)
```

so that given:

```
d = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': {'a': 'c'},
    'c': [
        {'a': 'd'},
        {'b': 'e'}
    ]
}
```

`list(extract(d, 'a'))` returns:

```
[[1, 2, 3], 'c', 'd']
```